# How to join tables in query

Tags: android, xamarin, sqlite.net

I am using sqlite.net component of Xamarin to develop database application.I am able to do database operations on single table with ORM tightly coupled model.

Eg. If I have XYZ model and XYZ table in DB I can fire query and able to get list of XYZ objects from tables.
Here data structure used was XYZ for ExecuteQuery operation.

But, If I need to do select operation on multiple tables with say join query then what data structure I can use, as it should be combined type of two tables/ models, also there is no single table involved in query. Is there anything in c# like cursors in android?

Note: I have found SqlDataReader in System.Data.Sqlite namespace.but its not there in SQLite.cs library.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created new model to store data which will not be a table but just a model to store query data.